# How to merge several `application.properties` from dependency module

Tags: quarkus

I want to provide default configurations and features to all my Quarkus projects.

Say I want to set up some filters, and they need config properties from `application.properties`.
If I provide such a file from my library, it is replaced with the one from the application project in the application uber-jar.

What I would like to achieve is something similar to the [merge feature](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/#appending-text-files) of the Shadow gradle plugin, merging all the `application.properties` from all the jars, appending the one from the application last to the built file.

Comment: Is there any reason you really need `uber-jar`?

Comment: We don't do native and run the uber-jars. that would be the main one. But even for the native solution, we could need to merge the libs' `application.properties`  and the application's.

Comment: My point is that you can use the `fast-jar` which is the default used in Quarkus and this problem would no longer exist as things don't have to be merged in that case.